# TrippLite PDUVM5NET SNMP MIB for Current

Tags: snmp

Trying to monitor some TrippLite switched/metered vertical PDUs with PRTG using SNMP. I can't seem to find any MIB that would provide me with the output current.

Anyone have experiencing monitoring these TrippLite PDUs with SNMP? I've download both the TRIPPLITE-MIB and UPS-MIB from their website, but neither of these files contains an entry to current in amps.

EDIT:

1. MIBS downloaded from [here](http://www.tripplite.com/support/model/mid/PDUMV20NET)
2. Running the following snmpwalk command `snmpwalk -v2c -c tripplite 192.168.15.25 1.3.6.1.4.1.850.100.1.4` which is responding with `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.850.100.1.4 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

Comment: Is `tlUpsOutletCurrent 1.3.6.1.4.1.850.100.1.10.2.1.13` not in amps?

Comment: `➜  mibs  snmpwalk -v2c -c tripplite 192.168.15.25 1.3.6.1.4.1.850.100.1.10.2.1.13 
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.850.100.1.10.2.1.13 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

Comment: This is where I got one for a Tripp Lite: http://www.oidview.com/mibs/850/TRIPPLITE-MIB.html  There are instructions on the page that include: `To query a live agent with SNMP for objects in module TRIPPLITE-MIB, use OidView Network Management Tools or SNMP SNMP MIB Browser.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [this is the MIB](http://www.tripplite.com/shared/software/Firmware/Tripp-Lite-MIB-Definitions.txt) that you're referring to, I see the following table:

```
tlUpsOutputCircuitTable
```

With each row in the table being:

```
tlUpsOutputCircuitIndex     PositiveInteger,
tlUpsOutputCircuitStatus    INTEGER,
tlUpsOutputCircuitLoadCurrent   NonNegativeInteger
```

Presumably `tlUpsOutputCircuitLoadCurrent` would be what you want, and represents the amps in tenths?

EDIT: Try telling Net-SNMP where to load the MIBs from when you run `snmpwalk`. Assuming you've saved those MIB files to `/home/ethan/.snmp/mibs` you would do the following:

```
snmpwalk -M +/home/ethan/.snmp/mibs -m +TRIPPLITE-MIB -v2c -c 'tripplite' 192.168.15.25 tlUpsOutputCircuitTable
```

If that still returns an error, the next step would be to just run a bulkwalk on the unit to see what OIDs **are** available, as the SNMP agent on the device may not export everything that's available in TRIPPLITE-MIB.

```
snmpbulkwalk -M +/home/ethan/.snmp/mibs -m +TRIPPLITE-MIB -v2c -c 'tripplite' 192.168.15.25
```

Comment: That's whats confusing me. When I snmpwalk on the device I don't even see those OIDs showing up. According to [this page](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/850/TRIPPLITE-MIB.html) I should be able to use OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.850.100.1.4.7.1.3` to get load current, but I'm getting 'No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

Comment: Can you edit the original question with the following information: 1) Where are you keeping your MIBs and 2) How you're calling the snmpwalk command?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, John. However I'm still getting the same message: `TRIPPLITE-MIB::tlUpsOutputCircuitTable = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

This device isn't a UPS, so maybe its a bit different. I assumed they used the same MIBS for their entire product line. Not sure why the PDUVM20NET is not responding to these OIDs.

Comment: I would run the `snmpbulkwalk` then to see what objects out of TRIPPLITE-MIB are exported from your PDU.

Comment: That helped, now I'm seeing some useful data. `UPS-MIB::upsOutputCurrent.1 = INTEGER: 40 0.1 RMS Amp`. Looks like this is 4 amps. Thanks for the help!